# How do I find the angles of a polygon if I only have the lengths of the sides?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, polygons

I have the length of n sides $[l_1,l_2,...,l_n]$ and it is possible to form a polygon using these sides. The sides of the polygon will be in the order as given so the adjacent sides of $l_1$ are $l_n$ and $l_2$ and like that. How do I find the interior angles of the polygon? I know there can be multiple lists of angles for 1 list of sides, I just need any one.

Comment: Note that if one length $\ell_i $ exceeds the sum of the others, no polygon is possible.  Do you care whether the polygon constructed is convex?

Comment: Yes, the polygon should be convex and lengths are such that it is possible to form a convex polygon. No $L_i$ exceeds the sum of the others.

Comment: One approach that uniquely determines interior angles is to require the polygon of [maximum area enclosed](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930607/maximum-area-enclosure-given-side-lengths).  See whether the answers to that recent Question are useful to you.

Answer (score 3):

Two suggestions:

(1) Use the "2-kinks" theorem to form a triangle from your lengths. (*[Computational Geometry in C](http://cs.smith.edu/~orourke/books/compgeom.html)*, p.330). 
Then several angles are $180^\circ$, and three are triangle angles.

(2) Form a cyclic polygon from your lengths by shrinking the radius of a circle until your lengths close to a polygon:

---

[image: CycPoly]

---

See [this MSE posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1930026/237) for cyclic polygon calculations,
or the reference by @hardmath (in a comment)
to [another MSE posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1930607/237) on cyclic polygons.