What is the maximum area that can be enclosed in a polygon formed by n wires?
The problem is that we have n wires of different lengths, i.e. $w_1,w_2,...,w_n$. The wires are aligned in a way such that they enclose the maximum area. What is that maximum area, or its best approximation?
I understand that this would become a cyclic polygon since all the points would lie on a circle for this condition to hold. Is there a mathematical expression that can approximate the area of such a polygon in terms of the lengths only.
I did the following to get the area, but I don't know how to move it further to get a better approximate value in terms of the lengths:
$$Area_{polygon} = Area_{circle} - \sum Area_{circularSegments}$$
$$= \pi r^2 - 1/2r^2(\sum \theta_i - \sum \sin(\theta_i))$$
$$= \pi r^2 - 1/2r^2(2\pi - \sum \sin(\theta_i))$$
$$= r^2/2(\sum \sin(\theta_i))$$
I'd appreciate any help!

You are going to want to find $r$ which I would guess would be the solution to $\sum \sin^{-1}\left(\frac{w_i}{2r}\right)=\pi$, at which point $\theta_i=2\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{w_i}{2r}\right)$

I added an answer in  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930607/maximum-area-enclosure-given-side-lengths/4925300#4925300
